# Recommend a book on load-testing an ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, performance, load-testing, stress-testing

I need a book to recommend strategies for load-testing an ASP.NET application with SQL Server backend.

Some info that may be useful:

- how to write a load test plan
- what perfmon counters to use and
  typical threshold values
- finding bottlenecks
- various load testing tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has a Patterns & Practice book called ["Performance Testing Guidance for Web Applications"](http://perftestingguide.codeplex.com/releases/view/6690)

I haven't read it, but I've skimmed through it, and it looks like something that you or others would find beneficial.  Plus, it's free.

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend two books published in 2010:

1. [".NET Performance Testing and Optimization - The Complete Guide, by Paul Glavich, Chris Farrell"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1906434409).
2. ["ASP.NET SITE PERFORMANCE SECRETS"](http://free-ebooks-site.com/asp-net-site-performance-secrets) by [Matt Perdeck](http://advancedwebsitetechnology.com/)

The first book is pretty complete source for performance testing. It reflects all 4 topics listed in the question. The second book is written more from performance optimization standpoint, but also discusses in-depth bottlenecks, perfmon counters and load testing tools. It is also a free pdf eBook.